# Parsing logs and adding count to list

Tags: python

I have the following script that wrote in order to parse some logs. The script works fine, but now i want to add something that will count the duplicates and add that to the list. I have been trying to add that little piece for the last few days and i can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be very much appreciated. I am trying to add it in the function called strip_dupes, or maybe i am looking at it wrong and need to create a new function all together to do this.

```
import sys
import collections

def strip_dupes(lst):
    seen = set()
    keep = []
    for sd in lst:
        if sd in seen:
            print(“Duplicate Found: %s” % (sd,))
        else:
            seen.add(sd)
            keep.append(sd)

    final_list = keep
return final_list

def format_traffic(ltpl,fname):
    ofile = open(output_file, “w”)
    for s,d,t in ltpl:
        ofile.write(“Source %s -> Destination: %s -> Service: %s\n” % (s,d,t))
    ofile.close()


log_file = open(sys.argv[1], “r”)
lines = log_file.readlines()
output_file = sys.argv[2]
traffic_list = []

for l in lines:
    words = l.split()
    source = words[9].strip(‘“‘)
    dest     = words[10].strip(‘“‘)
    serv     = words[7].strip(‘“’)
    flow = (source, dest, serv)
    traffic_list.append(flow)

final = strip_dupes(traffic_list)
format_traffic(final,output_file)
log_file.close()
```

Comment: It seems thet the indentation of  "return final_list" is not right. It is outside the function strip_dupes()

Comment: It works fine when i run it, it might have to do with the editor being used, i also had that indentation error when using python3

Comment: I tried to add a line where it says "if sd in seen:" but the problem is it will count every time it sees a duplicate, i need to it to count every time it sees a particular duplicate and add that count to the list for that specific connection